# Need to pull lines that contain the pattern in the middle, but not end of the line

Tags: grep

so I have a bunch of lines of characters and all lines end with 8
some lines also have 8 in the middle of them, and I'd like to pull those lines that have 8 in the middle out specifically from the file
here's an example of what a line with 8 in the middle would look like

> lcl|XM_024182377.1_cds_XP_024038145.1_1
> MSDLTELFTWTCSRCDGLTKGFLGVAKDLNAIVIAFRGTQEHSIQNWIEDLFWKQLDINYPGMSDAMVHH
> GFYSAYHNTTIRPAIINAVERAKDFYGD8LNIMVTGHSMGGAMAAFCGLDLTVNLGIQNVQVMTFGQPRIG
> NAAFASYYTQLVPNTFRVTNDHDIVPHLPPYYSYFPQKTYHHFPREVWLYHIGLGSLIYEVEKICDGSGE
> DPSCSRSVTGNSVSDHLVYFGVRMGCNEWTPCRIVMDPRVAEYGKTDLKGNFILSRPPAASILKLRTDSD
> AAGNHF8

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format sample input, expected output, and code and then [edit] your question to provide all 3 so we can best help you. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to use `awk` or `sed` when multiple conditions are needed:

```
awk '!/8$/ && /8/' file
```

This selects lines for printing based on 2 conditions: that it *does not* match the anchored regex `8$` and *does* match `8`. The same logic in sed: `sed -n '/8$/!{/8/p;}'`.

With `sed` and a slightly different logic:

```
sed '/8$/d; /8/!d' file
```

This filters lines by deleting those that match `8$` or don't match `8`. The same logic in awk: `awk '/8$/ || !/8/ {next} 1'`.

Or `grep`x2:

```
grep -v 8$ <file | grep 8
```

Reject lines ending in 8 with the first pass. Select lines containing 8 with the second pass.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements aren't clear but to print lines that have `8` in the middle regardless of whether or not they also have 8 at the end, which is what I **think** you want, would just be:

```
grep '8.' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
grep -E '8.+$' <FILE>
```

Comment: this returned every single line in the file

Comment: Then there are 8s in the middle of every line or you need to rephrase your question.  This regex matches an 8 followed by one or more characters.

Comment: `.+$` doesn't seem like it would be useful with `grep` (`.` would get the same result). `8.*[^8]$` might work.